# Проблема с обращением к функции из списка sys.argv

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, файловая-система

у меня такая проблема:
Из консоли парсингом аргументов я получаю строку, которая содержит в себе название функции

```
D:\Python\YandexDiskProject> testSysArgv.py load
```

в данном случае - метод `load` (заранее существует),
далее я пытаюсь попасть в эту функцию, что вызывает ошибку

```
import sys


sys.argv[1]()
def load():
    print('Yahooo')
```

Но это вызывает ошибку:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Так как сделать так, чтобы можно было переходить в функцию, получив системный аргумент?

Comment: `locals()[sys.argv[1]]()`

Comment: Никита, немножко подумать нужно, совсем немножко.

Comment: Верно, спасибо, почему-то запускалась старая версия программы даже после сохранения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys

def load():
    print('Yahooo')

locals()[sys.argv[1]]()
```